# Canvas element is undefined

Tags: javascript, canvas

coudl someone have a look at this piece of code and tell me why I get the canvas element undefined? or why I can not use this kind of syntax?

```
var Canvas = {

   element : document.getElementById("canvas"),
   context : Canvas.element.getContext("2d"), // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare it this way. The best thing you can do is:

```
var Canvas = {
   element: document.getElementById("canvas"),
   context: document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")
}
```

If your `Canvas` was a function and you stored element in `this`, then you can access it through `this.element`:

```
var Canvas = function (id) {
    this.element = document.getElementById(id);
    this.context = this.element.getContext('2d');
}
```